# Editing and reading a .txt file with batch commands

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I'm trying to create a batch file for an automated testing script.
Everytime the batch for the master script is started up, it should open an existing .txt-file in the same directory containing something like this:

```
10.200.6.111 inactive
10.200.6.112 inactive
10.200.6.113 inactive
10.200.6.114 inactive  
etc...
```

It should then navigate to the line with it's own IP (which is specified in the batch) and replace the 'inactive' tag with 'active' (indicating that this system has now started testing). Ideally it would also append a timestamp, maybe with something along these lines:

`for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=:" %%d in ("%time%") //and then add %%d-%%e at the end?`

I've tried to do something similar before and also looked through existing topics but everything seems to be very specific to one situation and I lack the skills to adapt them myself. Ultimately I would need a different .bat to also read from this file and delay any action until all 'active' tabs are gone. But since as of now there is only one vm doing the testing, it would really be a weight off my shoulder if I could just get this to work. Thanks in advance for any help and I apologize if this is a duplicate, I really did try to find something I could use!

*PS:* I'm really terrible at 'getting' generic code sometimes, it's perfectly possible this has been clearly answered before and I'm just not capable of understanding the solution.

*Edit:* Just to clarify, it should look roughly like this:

```
10.200.6.111 inactive
10.200.6.112 inactive
10.200.6.113 active 14:20
10.200.6.114 inactive  
etc...
```

*Edit 2:* Actually, after thinking about it some more, I've concluded that I can probably do it better by just using my scripts and keeping the batch files simple.

Comment: How is the batch getting its current IP address?

Comment: Oh no sry, that isn't a dynamic value. It's just the ip of that specific virtual machine, it will always be the same and I could therefore just write it into the nescessary .bat file on each system (once there are multiple vms). In this case the .bat should search for 10.200.6.111.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

:: define the log file

    set "file=%~nx0.test.txt"

:: generate some lines in log file to test

    if not exist "%file%" (   
        echo 10.200.6.111 inactive
        echo 10.200.6.112 inactive
        echo 10.200.6.113 inactive
        echo 10.200.6.114 inactive
    ) > "%file%"

:: define the ip of the current node
    set "ip=10.200.6.114"

:: change status in log file to active and shows sucess/failure of operation
    call :changeStatus "%file%" "%ip%" "active %time:~0,5%" 
    if errorlevel 1 (
        echo failed to change status
    ) else (
        echo status changed
    )

:: dump file to see changes
    call :dumpFile "%file%"

:: change status in log file to inactive
    call :changeStatus "%file%" "%ip%" "inactive" 

:: dump file to see changes
    call :dumpFile "%file%"

    exit /B


:dumpFile file
    echo(
    echo(----------------------------------
    type "%~1"
    echo(----------------------------------
    echo(
    exit /b


:changeStatus file ip status
    setlocal enableextensions
    set "file=%~1"
    set "ip=%~2"
    set "status=%~3"
    set "retries=0123456789"
    set "exitCode=0"
:changeStatusRetry
    (>"%file%.lock" (
        set "reset=1"
        for /f "usebackq tokens=1*" %%a in ("%file%") do (
            if defined reset ( set "reset=" & >"%file%" break )
            (if "%%a"=="%ip%" (
                echo(%%a %status%
            ) else (
                echo(%%a %%b
            )) >> "%file%"
        )
    ) && set "exitCode=0" || set "exitCode=1") >nul 2>nul 
    if "%exitCode%"=="1" (
        ping -n 2 localhost >nul 2>nul 
        set "retries=%retries:~0,-1%"
        if defined retries ( set "exitCode=0" & goto changeStatusRetry ) 
    )
    del /q "%file%.lock" >nul 2>nul 
    endlocal & exit /b %exitCode%
```

This uses a subroutine to handle the changes to log file. It also handles locking on the file from multiple processes. Log file access is locked while changing data and if at the time of changing the file it is locked, it retries up to 10 times to write changed data. On return from the subroutine, errorlevel indicates the result of the operation.

Comment: @hiyosilver, updated answer. Sorry for the delay, i just wanted to test it.

Comment: Wow, this actually looks really cool. I'm still struggling with getting this to work since my script just won't do the job and I can't tell why. I'll try this right away. Tbh, I'm not 100% sure which parts I need to replace with my own specific data and which are fine the way they are...

Comment: it'd be amazing if you could help me split this thing into two parts. I want the batch to place the logfile into a specific shared directory and then call a different batch for testing. I need a second batch (to be executed maybe an hour later when those tests are likely finished) which loops through the log for about 30 minutes or so in the manner I described in my original post, to determine if any system is currently testing. Only if no 'active' tag can be found should this second batch call yet another batch to start running the tests.

Comment: I think I understand most of your code, but I can't figure out how to split it the way I need it. Also there seems to be no check of the current status of the file in place, other than looking for the change manually.

Comment: @hiyosilver, There is a subroutine that accepts a file as a parameter and handles the state change. Place it with the adecuated code to initialize the ip var into a batch file in the shared folder. Call this batch from the batch files that that start the testing, signaling they are active. Call again from the same batch files when the tests are finished to signal inactive status. The check status batch is just a loop with a findstr command to search the " active " text in the file and a timeout/ping command to wait between tests.

Comment: My first reaction was 'oh god, I don't understand any of this!'. But after looking at all the code again, trying to understand and then looking up the other things you mentioned, I'm finally done. I think I've actually set it up in a way that writes the files, reads them and reacts properly. Thank you so much for your help, I would have never been able to do this on my own. Sadly I can't give you any upvotes but you have my gratitude. :)